# Ubuntu 16.04 installed but wifi does not work. Configuration file attached

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless

I just installed Ubuntu 16.04 but the wifi does not seem to work. I have run the following code and [pasted the results](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24200982/) :

```
wget -N -t 5 -T 10 https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info && chmod +x wireless-info && ./wireless-info
```

Comment: Will you append the output of `sudo lshw -c network&&rfkill list` to our question?